# How to insert particular values into Mongodb using Angularjs MEAN STACK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, mongojs

I store input values into mongodb using scope name. I have a 3 fields when I click add all values are in object so I directly send the scope name into server and store it.

I would like to store only 2nd textbox values and remaining values should be NULL into the database. But I don't know how to do this. Anyone can help me?

> Server.js

```
app.post('/AddNewcontact', function (req, res) {
    db.Manage_Facility.insert(req.body, function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});
```

> controller.js

```
$scope.AddNew = function () {
        $http.post('/AddNewcontact', $scope.Contact).success(function (response) { 

        });
    };
```

> html

```
<input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" ng-model="Contact.Name">
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="Contact.email">
<input type="text" name="cellno" class="form-control" ng-model="Contact.cellno">
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="AddNew()" >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
controller.js
  $scope.AddNew = function () {

        $http.post('/AddNewcontact',{ 'Name': $scope.Contact.email}).success(function (response) {      

        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to send just the email, do following :

**delete $scope.Contact.Name;**

**delete $scope.Contact.cellno;**

here is example

```
$http.post('/AddNewcontact', $scope.Contact).success(function (response) {      

        });
```